# How to configure a custom port to file system using s3a in flink 1.11

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to connect to a local rados GW listening to port 1234
when I configure *fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled* to false it connects to 80 (http)
And when its true (or not set) it connects to 443 (https)

How can I change the port to connect to a different port? 
Is there a flink configuration that I can use (beside configure core-site.xml)

I'm working on flink 1.11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `s3.endpoint` and point it to `http://<machine>:<port>`. (Use `fs.s3a.endpoint` when you use both s3 plugins)

Comment: Adding 'fs.s3a.endpoint: http://180.150.0.33:1234' with 'http:// before  did the trick , only  180.150.0.33:1234 without the http prefix , throws exception ' Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 180.150.0.33:1234'